# Firebase Authentication with Facebook Redirect Method (different results from redirect versus already logged in)

Tags: facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication, angularfire2

I am using firebase to authenticate users through a Facebook redirect. The issue I am running into is that I am getting different responses from the authentication directly after the redirect verses if someone is already logged in.

```
let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('user_friends');
this.FIREAUTH.signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

I am using angular fire to subscribe to the data and this function gives me different responses. My question is why are they different and what can I do after the redirect to finish the login? Firebase doesn't seem to see that I am logged in after the redirect.

```
authSubscribe(reader) {
  this.af.auth.subscribe(data => {
    if (data && data.uid) {this.uid = data.uid;}
    console.log('authentication subscribe: ', data);
    reader(data);
  });
}
```

after redirect
[image: after redirect]

on refresh when already logged in
[image: on refresh when already logged in]

Answer (score 0):

Some mistake here:

```
authSubscribe(reader) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(data => {
        if (data && data.uid) {this.uid = data.uid;}
        console.log('authentication subscribe: ', data);
        reader(data);
    });
}
```

If you check the console, it should be like this:

```
authSubscribe(reader) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(data => {
        if (data && data.auth.uid) {this.uid = data.auth.uid;}
        console.log('authentication subscribe: ', data);
        reader(data);
    });
}
```

data.auth.uid, not data.uid.
auth is an object

Comment: hey thanks for trying to help, firebase returns the UID outside of the auth object also. Sorry I didn't have that in my screenshot! My issue is with the facebook object returning different values at different stages of authentication.